# I want to know why the function are always choose the first one and how to fixed it -Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I have here is a small part of source code, I'm a newbie just start learning this month and try to make this game work, I don't know much thing work here. My question is after I run this when n1 or n2 is the same number I put in it still run in a loop in the first 'if' I want it to run in the last 'elif'I want someone who can tell what the source code problem I have now, because I don't understand... If I have bad English here don't mind me please... and still how can I made my  score work because by my try over a week I still have no clue..

import random

def EasyMode():

```
    n1 = random.randint(5, 9)
    n2 = random.randint(1, 4)
    player = int(input("Select a room from 1 to 9: "))
   # while n0 != player:
    while True:

        if player != n1 or n2:
            print("You have been survire!")
            print("First Trapper", n1)
            print("Second Trapper", n2)
            ScoreCountE()
        elif player > 10:
            print("STOP CHEATING")
            ScoreCountE()
        elif player == n1 or n2:
            print("You were capture by the trapper" + '\n' + "Game Over!")
            break
        else:
            break
```

def ScoreCountE():

```
score = 0
while score >= 0:
    score = score + 1
    print(score)
    return score and EasyMode()
```

EasyMode()

Comment: It's player!=n1 or player !=n2 similarly for last elif

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple: `elif player != n1 or n2` is not the same as `elif player != n1 or player != n2`.

`player != n1 or n2` is the same as `(player != n1) or (bool(n2))`. In other words, as long as `n2` is "truthy" (something that, when converted to a boolean, will be `True`), `player != n1 or n2` will be `True`. Since `n2` is always a nonzero `int`, it is always truthy, and therefore your `if` condition will always succeed.

Also, you change the values of `player`, `n1` and `n2` only *outside* your `while` loop. That means that your code inside of that loop will always take the same path! Judging from your code, I think you want `player = int(input("Select a room from 1 to 9: "))` inside the loop.

As an aside: if you ever were in a situation where you wanted to compare inequality to many variables (something like `player != n1 or player != n2 or player != n3...`), you could use `player in [n1, n2, n3...]` instead.

Comment: Thank your! this help me understand much more, but still confusing me some how...

Comment: @Shahalan What confuses you?

Comment: after I do right what you say, the result is first one not work but other is still?

Comment: @Shahalan Did you change both `if`s? Also, I realise there's one more mistake in your code; will edit my answer.

Comment: yep, i change both and the answer is come with two result, 1. else = break 2. Stop cheating work like a loop until the my number are the same as trapper number

Comment: Thank your again... I can figure it out now !